# How to approve a PR using Azure Git api

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-git-deployment

I am trying to create a PR using Git Azure API

[Azure git api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers/create%20pull%20request%20reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Base on the documentation as part of the request body you have a field: **vote** that has these values:

```
Vote on a pull request:
10 - approved 5 - approved with suggestions 0 - no vote -5 - waiting for author -10 - rejected
```

I tried to pass a 10 but the PR is created but not approved.
I want to approve the PR even if I get a conflict.
Any idea of what am I missing here?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I tested but it seemed to work but I try it again, and now I am getting an Authorization issue with the same token I have, let me see if I can post that later for you

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Request URL

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/pullRequests/{pull request ID}/reviewers/{reviewerId}?api-version=6.0
```

Request body:

```
{
  "hasDeclined": false,
  "id": "{reviewerId}",
  "vote": 10
}
```

Result:

PostMan

[image]

UI:

[image]